# SWT/JFace equivalent to JComponent.setDefaultLocale()?

Tags: java, swt, jface

In Swing, if I want to set the default locale used by components, I can call [`JComponent.setDefaultLocale()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDefaultLocale%28java.util.Locale%29).  I want to do the same thing in SWT/JFace, so my JFace dialogs use a locale of my choosing to display the OK/Cancel buttons, etc.  Is there an equivalent method in the SWT/JFace API that I can call?

I am aware that I could call [`Locale.setDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29), but I would like to avoid this because there are other parts of the application where I need this to be the system default locale, instead of the locale of my choosing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've seen in the source code - especially where the values of `IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL` and similar constants originate - JFace completely relies on the default locale (`Locale.getDefault()`). Using SWT directly, e.g. `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox`, will even ignore the Java default locale and display the dialog in the system's locale. So there seem's to be no SWT/JFace equivalent of `JComponent.setDefaultLocale()`.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know you should be able to use the locale of your choice using :

- the swt-nl.jar library (to be included in your classpath)
- setting the user.language library with something like this java -cp ... -Duser.language=fr MainApp

Please check to download the correct swt-nl pack for your needs , different are available ...

HTH
jerome

Comment: Setting `user.language` does work, but it seems that's because it alters the default locale setting...if I print `Locale.getDefault()` I get `fr_US`, instead of `en_US`